# RegEx pattern to search characters before the "@" in an email

Tags: regex, mongodb

I want to be able to query the database for email addresses matching a regex. An example of what I am trying to avoid is this:
In my database, I have a user with emailAddress of `amy.user@gmail.com` 
I also have 700 users with the domain name `@amyconsulting.com`
The current search I have now will return 701 results instead of 1 when I try to search for Amy like so: `^.*amy.*$` 
 How can I make this search only the characters before the `@` symbol in the email address? Thanks in advance...

Comment: `^.*amy.*@` perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't likely cover all email cases, but given the examples you've posted, you can start from here to improve your regex:

```
.*(amy).*@[\w]+(\.)[\w]+
```

It accepts strings that contain the word `amy` before an email regex pattern. Again, I didn't look up the best regex for email, but this one gives the idea of how you should approach your problem.

I recommend using [Regex101](https://regex101.com/), there's a very cool playground in there which helps to learn new regex symbols to figure out your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the resource big fella

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a negated character class `[^@]*` matching 0+ occurrences of any char except `@`

If you don't want to match a newline as well, you could use `[^@\r\n]*` or `[^\s\@]` to not match whitespaces as well.

```
^[^@]*amy[^@]*@[^@]+$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[^@]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `@`
- `amy`
- `[^@]*` Match 0+ occurrences of any char except `@`
- `@` Match the `@`
- `[^@]+` Match 1+ occurrences of any char except `@`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V958Z8/1)